# Possible to call a specific audio channel within a filter graph?

Tags: audio, ffmpeg

I know that the `-map_channel` argument can specify a specific audio channel within a file, but is there a way to do a similar argument within a filter graph?

I'm hoping something like this would be possible:

```
-filter_complex "[0.0.0]showspectrum…[Left];[0.0.1]showspectrum…[Right]"
```

Is anything like that possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [`channelsplit` filter](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#channelsplit). Assuming a stereo input:

```
ffmpeg -i input -filter_complex \
"[0:a]channelsplit[l][r]; \
 [l]showspectrum=color=intensity,pad=0:ih*2[left]; \
 [r]showspectrum=color=intensity[right]; \
 [left][right]overlay=0:h[v]" \
-map "[v]" -map 0:a -c:v libx264 -c:a copy output.mkv
```

This is just an example to show how `channelsplit` can be used. If you really wanted `showspectrum` to separate the channels just do:

```
ffmpeg -i input -filter_complex "[0:a]showspectrum=mode=separate[v]" \
-map "[v]" -map [0:a] -c:v libx264 -c:a copy output.mkv
```